# Como comparar as linhas do select com o resultado de um subselect?

Tags: oracle

Tenho uma tabela com registro de atividades. Então encontro casos como o exemplo abaixo:

`|codigo| etapa |
 -       -      -
 |abc123|   1   |
 |abc123|   2   |
 |abc123|   3   |
 |xyz987|   1   |
 |xyz987|   2   |`

E eu preciso listar o codigo e a ultima etapa que esse codigo registrou.
Seria o seguinte resultado:

`|codigo| etapa |
 -       -      -
 |abc123|   3   |
 |xyz987|   2   |`

Então eu fiz a consulta:

`Select codigo, max(etapa) from tabela group by codigo`

Até ai tudo certo. Agora preciso comparar isso em um outro select.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

`Select * 
from tabela
where exists (Select codigo, max(etapa) from tabela group by codigo)`

Nesse caso o comando ignora o subselect e retorna tudo da tabela.
Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: se quiser usar um subselect da mesma tabela, precisa usar um alias para poder distinguir entre as duas, veja se o problema não é isso.. algo assim: `Select * 
from tabela t1
where exists (Select codigo, max(etapa) from tabela group by codigo)  WHERE tabela.campo = t1.campo`

Comment: No codigo que você colocou da erro pois tem dois WHERE seguidos, mas coloquei os alias corretamente e o resultado continua o mesmo.

Comment: ah sim era um exemplo, esse where viria antes do group by dentro dos parênteses, não me atentei qdo coloquei o comentário :)

Comment: sim sim, eu joguei ele pra dentro e continua com o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a sub-consulta  no select para trazer o resultado.
Adicionei o alias nas tabelas para poder filtrar pelo código
Adicionei também uma condição where no sub-select.

```
Select t1.* , (select  max(t2.etapa) from tabela as t2  where t2.codigo = t1.codigo group by t2.codigo)
from tabela t1
where exists (select t2.codigo from tabela t2  where t2.codigo = t1.codigo group by t2.codigo)
```

Comment: Tentei rodar esse codigo, mas o primeiro subselect apresenta o erro "parentese direito não encontrado". Tentei adaptar de todas as formas, mas o erro persiste.